# Xubuntu 16.04.1: Printer makes short noise when I turn my monitor on with Xubuntu machine running (really weird :O)

Tags: networking, 16.04, xubuntu, printing

Well, this one is deep... First a short description and after that I will go to details. I have my laptop in a docking station. When I power on my monitor with the laptop already powered on, my network printer starts to spin some motor inside it and it keeps noise. Everything in the whole setup works well: printer, monitor and laptop are all ok. But the noise is just annoying when I try to concentrate on my work.

And then the same again in a wall-of-text format :).

1. I have my Thinkpad T410 laptop powered on in a Lenovo dock.
2. The laptop is in the same network with my printer (Epson WorkForce WF-3620), using both wired and wireless connections. Print queue is empty both in the laptop and in the printer itself.
3. I power on my two monitors (both connected to the dock, one using DVI and another one using DisplayPort) by powering on an extension cord. Note that the printer is not connected to this extension cord - the printer is always powered. The extension cord is connected only to the monitors and to a desktop light. Laptop PSU is not connected to this extension cord.
4. Some motor starts spinning inside the printer. The printer's screen does not light up, the printer does not print anything and no outer parts of the printer are moving. The motor/noise is not even related to actual printing, because I was once printing a document from my other computer (Windows 10), and then turned on the laptop (with the motors already turned on, if I remember correctly), and when it booted, the printer made the same noise again at the same time when it was printing a document. It didn't pause the printing at all. This leads me to think that perhaps the noise comes from a motor that runs the waste ink pump. Perhaps the printer is doing some self cleaning and it can even do it when it has a print job in process. A really multi tasker! :D Or then it's something else - I do not know printer mechanics too well :/. Perhaps I should... before my printer starts to walk around my apartment when I use for example the microwave oven XD.
5. The spinning stops automatically after a few seconds.
6. If I turn the monitors off and on again just a little after the noise, it doesn't happen again. It needs some time before the printer makes the noise again. I really can't tell how long, but let's say something about half an hour or a couple of hours, for a guess.
7. My windows computer does not trigger the sound. It does not matter if it is on or off.

This is what came to my mind now. There are some things that I could test more to exclude some moving parts in the scenario. For example, power on the monitors one at a time. But for now, I just leave this question here and see if someone has already some new ideas I haven't had thought of yet.

The symptom appeared right after I bought a new hard drive for my laptop and installed Xubuntu 16.04. Before that it had Xubuntu 15.04 or Xubuntu 14.04. Nothing else in the setup has changed: printer is old, but main monitor and my router are a few months old, but they still were part of the setup when the laptop had Xubuntu 15.04/14.04. Dock and KVM are also old.

P.S. I tried to google before I posted this. Just had no clue how to form the question as it's so complicated :D. So, as I found nothing, I guess no one has asked anything like this - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you for your support! :)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Is the printer connected to the laptop with a USB cable? Does the cable have [ferrite beads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead)?

Comment: I would assume that the Xubuntu system checks out that a (known) device is connected. Maybe the check mechanism has changed between the older versions and 16.04. The question is: is it a bug or a feature in the driver? Try to uninstall the printer driver, boot again and look if it happens again.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Thanks! Oh, that was one thing I forgot to mention, there is no USB cord between the printer and the laptop. The printer is only connected via LAN.

Comment: @Goetz Thanks, I will to try to uninstall the driver. I will report what happens when I have done that.

Comment: @user2754026 does this happen if the laptop is not plugged to the wall?